# Why does implementation work and not provided when upgrading to version 0.68 of react-native?

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native, dependencies

I just upgraded to react-native 0.68 and a dependency was no longer working, by inspecting the problem I was able to fix it by modifying a word in the build.gradle file of the dependency, what is the difference, why does it work with implementation and not with provided?

```
dependencies {
    // provided "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
}
```